# When and why do you need to use PtrSafe

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would like to know how you know whether you even need to declare `PtrSafe` in your Microsoft Access database for an ACCDE to work on a 32-bit version of Microsoft Access.  To my knowledge, I do not have any statements with the word Declare in them.  My database has tons of subs and one global dim variable in a few forms, but that's it.  I recently had someone unable to open my ACCDE file, and he got a 64-bit message error, but I have no idea even where to find which code is giving him issues.  I'm not an expert with Access or VBA and don't quite understand when the PtrSafe statement needs to be used or not used.

Comment: On your side note: This is a question and answer site. Please note that *question* is singular, not plural. If you have more than one question, you'll need to ask them in separate posts. I've edited your post to remove that separate, second question. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: `PtrSafe` by definition only applies to `Declare` statements. If you don't have any, you cannot and don't need to use `PtrSafe`.

Comment: And note that `PtrSafe` means you thoroughly checked the declaration to be safe for 64-bits pointers, which means: don't go slapping it onto functions without thorough checking to make errors go away because that will likely lead to your application randomly crashing on 64-bits windows (I've seen plenty of that, unfortunately).

Comment: The answer from @ChrisStrickland is correct and therefore this question was incorrectly closed as a duplicate ...

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: the problem wasn't PtrSafe.  The problem was that the file was an accde.  The accdb file is bit agnostic, as long as PtrSafe rules are followed or no declare statements are used, but the accde has a bitness, meaning if it's compiled on a 64 bit version, it will only open on a 64 bit version.

===================================================

You'll need to use PtrSafe if your code will ever need to execute on a 64 bit version AND you are using DECLARE statements to interact with the Win32.api.  See the section on api compatibility in the second link for more.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ptrsafe-keyword

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/shared/compatibility-between-the-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-office

Comment: Ok, yes, I get that part, but if I don't have any Declare statements in my existing code, how do I even implement the PtrSafe in my code?  Do I have to take every existing Private Sub and declare it at the very beginning, where it says Option Compare Database?  I've seen examples that involve things that already used Declare in before and after, so I am not sure how I can apply existing VBA that's almost entirely made of private subs, where the word Declare has never been used, and implement PtrSafe into it.

Can I see an example of this in before and after?

Comment: In the second link, look for the section on API compatibility.  It explains why there is a need for PtrSafe at all, and what situations you would need to use it in.  Are you having some trouble with your existing applications on 32 bit systems?  Or are you just asking?

Comment: Yes, I had one person who could not open an ACCDE file I created and got a 32 bit/64 bit warning message.

Comment: what is the text of the message?

Comment: and does it happen on all 32 bit versions or just for one user?

Comment: The message of the ACCDE says "This file was created with the 64-bit version of Access.  Please open it with the 64-bit version of Access."  Is this a PtrSafe problem, or something else?

Comment: The message displays for multiple users who have the 32-bit version.

Comment: Ok, I believe that the accdb is bit agnostic UNLESS you have DECLARE statements that need PtrSafe, but the accde compiled file can only be opened with the same bitness as the version that created it.  So to test if that is the problem, you will need to find a 32 bit version, open the accdb and compile to accde on that computer, then try opening that file on the computers that are having trouble.

Comment: Hmm, ok, so what you're saying is that a 32-bit user MUST upgrade to 64-bit in order to use my ACCDE file?

Comment: Or you can create a 32 bit accde for 32 bit users.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You'd have to compile the accde from the accdb on a 32 bit version.

Comment: Oh wow, is it that easy?  Like, can I just open my ACCDB file (created on a 64-bit system) on a 32-bit system and create a new ACCDE from there?

Comment: You should be able to.  Bear in mind that I have never done it, but the accdb is supposed to be bit agnostic.  It's the compiled file that has a bitness.

Comment: Great, I'll have to give that a try! Thank you!

Comment: let me know how it works out

Comment: Hi Chris, this seemed to solve my problems!  I created two versions of the ACCDE, one for 64-bit and one for 32-bit.  Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Great to hear it.  If this question wasn't closed I would get you to select my answer, but it is.

Comment: Unfortunately all the last 10 or so comments were not visible when I first viewed this answer. The question was incorrectly closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Hi Chris, I did not choose the answer, that was probably the moderator.  I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I know you didn't.  You can't.  The question was marked as a duplicate and closed, because there are plenty of other questions about ptrsafe on here, it's just that ptrsafe wasn't really your problem.   Somebody with sufficient rep would have to come along and reopen the question.  It's not a big deal.  Glad your problem is fixed, and maybe it will help somebody else in the future.